# How can I get a raised border on a column header?

Tags: java, swing

How can I get a raised border in the "Check" column, like I have in the other ones? I found a question similar to this one, but here I'm using `InternalJFrame`, and `main` isn't available.

Here's a screenshot showing what I mean:

[image]

And here's my code:

```
class CheckBoxHeader extends JCheckBox implements TableCellRenderer, MouseListener {
    protected CheckBoxHeader rendererComponent;
    protected int column;
    protected boolean mousePressed = false;

    public CheckBoxHeader(ItemListener itemListener) {
        rendererComponent = this;
        rendererComponent.addItemListener(itemListener);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        if (table != null) {
            JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
            if (header != null) {
                rendererComponent.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                Color lightYellow= new Color(255, 255, 170);
                rendererComponent.setBackground(lightYellow);
                rendererComponent.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.BOLD, 14));
                setOpaque(true);
                rendererComponent.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder());
                setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
                header.addMouseListener(rendererComponent);
            }
        }
        setColumn(column);
        rendererComponent.setText(value.toString());
        //setBorder(UIManager.getBorder("TableHeader.cellBorder"));
        return rendererComponent;
    }

    protected void setColumn(int column) {
        this.column = column;
    }

    public int getColumn() {
        return column;
    }

    protected void handleClickEvent(MouseEvent e) {
        if (mousePressed) {
            mousePressed=false;
            JTableHeader header = (JTableHeader)(e.getSource());
            JTable tableView = header.getTable();
            TableColumnModel columnModel = tableView.getColumnModel();
            int viewColumn = columnModel.getColumnIndexAtX(e.getX());
            int column = tableView.convertColumnIndexToModel(viewColumn);

            if (viewColumn == this.column && e.getClickCount() == 1 && column !=  -1)    {
                doClick();
            }
        }
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        handleClickEvent(e);
        ((JTableHeader)e.getSource()).repaint();
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        mousePressed = true;
    }
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }
}

class MyItemListener implements ItemListener
{
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source instanceof AbstractButton == false) return;
        boolean checked = e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED;
        for(int x = 0, y = DailydatasTbl.getRowCount(); x < y; x++)
        {
            // DailydatasTbl.setValueAt(new Boolean(checked),x,0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: after Changing code header.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder()); getting border on the bottom but still right side border is empty.

Comment: I edited the question so the English is better and there's only one question in it. I also added a relevant tag and change the title to be more accurate.